# how to get the line where the program crashes

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I have a c++ program and I want to display  the line number of where the program crashes in the console ! I'm using VS2010! is that even possible? I use opencv , and opencv does it ! 
any idea?

Comment: Either launch the app in the debugger or attach the debugger to the already running process. That is always the best place to start.

Comment: well, what kind of error occurrs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a same issue, there was a code and I wasn't able to debug it (it had to run without stopping). I put below code before every suspecting line:

```
cout << __LINE__ << endl;
```

After that, when it crashed, I could *trap* the problem.

---

But a standard way is using a debugger and put *conditional* breakpoints. (I'm not sure it helps you)

Comment: thanks MM for your answer it work but I don't know if I'm using it the right way please check my edited question

Comment: interesting aproach, but I'd first suggest using a debugger. But aren't you able to achieve the same thing with haltpoints instead of a debug message? It doesn't print the line but if the point is reached an the condition applies the it halts, indicating everything should have been ok till now

Comment: If the crash occurs inside a OpenCV function, find that function then recheck your passed arguments. I think you have a problem in your arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a debugger with reasonable haltpoints and check if those haltpoints are reached. I prefer this one over console debug messages as it doesn't pollute your code.

Comment: it's not about debuging it about integration a dll in a big program for that I need to no which line causes then problem . thanks anyway

Comment: i know what you mean, but using a debugger could help you. If you set a breakpoint somewhere and it isn't reached, then the error occurs before the breakpoint, so you have to move it a little backward

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you cannot use a debugger, e.g. when you cannot reproduce the crash locally. In this case you need to put `try/catch` on top-level to catch and report all exceptions (on Windows make sure you also catch structured exceptions) and to subscribe to [signals](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/) to catch and report `SEGFAULT`s etc.

Then you can log stack trace (not portable and requires debug symbols) or create a mini-dump (not portable).